# Getting Array from Another class C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am making a simple Lottery program - and am struggling with implementation. I have a class called 'Ticket Line' this class simply holds 6 numbers that the player is playing a lottery for.

What I want to do, is generate 6 randomly (got function for this already) and then store that in another class as values. To do this, I am using the following code:

```
  class Draw
{
private:
    int drawID; 
    TicketLine* DrawnNumbers;
    bool drawn; 
}
```

When a Draw is completed I want to generate the Random Numbers ( from the TicketLine class) and then for the Draw to be able to store those numbers into its Draw File.

How would I be able to access the functionality of the DrawnNumbers class - and store the results from the `getTicketNumbers.getTicketLine()`function.

```
int* getTicketNumbers(void) { return DrawnNumbers->getTicketLine();};
```

The program crashes the following code:

```
//int *ptr[6] = getTicketNumbers();
int *ptr[6] = getTicketNumbers();
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
    cout << ptr[x];
}
```

TicketLine class:

```
private: 
    int select[6]; //Array of Ticket Numbers.
int* getTicketLine(void) { return select; };
```

I am willing to offer a couple of virtual beers to the solution. I am as yet to find a good online pub - if you know of one then please do let me know :-)

Thanks,

Comment: "The following code doesn't work unfortunately" What do you mean ? It doesn't compile or it crashes at run time ? You don't give us enough information

Comment: @StephaneRolland Ha, he is one step ahead of you, he covered both cases with a single word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing any more, this line:

```
int *ptr[6] = getTicketNumbers();
```

is *very* suspect.

Why? Well, we haven't seen the implementation of `getTicketNumbers` so we don't know if it's actually allocating memory for 6 and returning such an array.

Also, you are printing the values of pointers here:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
    cout << ptr[x];
}
```

Where, if you intended to actually print the `int` values, you'd say something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
    cout << *(ptr[x]);
}
```

My guess is that you are either:

- Going out of bounds of an array that was (not) allocated, or,
- Modifying actual pointer values somewhere instead of the integers they point to (as indicated by your lack of dereferencing `ptr[x]` in your print statement)

### Edit

With more information, it seems you probably meant to say this:

```
int *ptr = getTicketNumbers();
```

instead of this:

```
int *ptr[6] = getTicketNumbers();
```

You should probably be doing some sanity checks as well to make sure that `select` is actually filled before calling that function (maybe giving it a default value of {0,0,0,0,0,0} in the constructor)

Comment: Hi, The getTicketNumbers(); is int* getTicketNumbers(void) { return DrawnNumbers->getTicketLine();}; (as mentioned above); 

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @KingJohnno: Please place the code in your original question. And format it, please.

Comment: All of the code is within the original question.

Comment: @KingJohnno: And that function implementation is not very expressive, because we don't know what `DrawnNumbers->getTicketLine()` does

Comment: Wait. `int *ptr[6]` declares `ptr` as an array 6 of pointers to int. I can bet he meant just `int (*ptr)[6]`.

Comment: Apologies - I will add it now. @AndyG added it now.

Answer (score 0):

DrawnNumbers doesn't appear to be pointing to anything yet. It's a pointer, but to what?

Also, be careful about returning arrays that way. If the object or stack frame that the array resides in goes away, you'll be left pointing to bad things.

Comment: DrawNumbers is an instance of the TicketLine class ?/